# Finding value of peer to peer pixel in another raster layer with same pixel size, coordinate and location from attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, pixel, unique-value

I have two raster layers with same pixel size, location, coordinate and time. I need to know what the value of defined pixel in one layer is in same location (pixel) in another raster layer.
The manual way in ArcGIS is i (identify) ,however there are 144 layers! I need an easier way

I work with ArcGIS for Desktop.

The images are LST and MODIS NDVI. The image of NDVI was Re-sampled.The pixel size is 5000m. I need to know the value of the right image.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: You say that you "work with ArcGIS 10.3 and ENVI 5.1" but which one of these have you actually tried to use to answer your own question, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with any requested clarifications.  By asking how to do this in either of two software products you are effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a point on the exact location of the pixel and then extract each pixel value on that same location from each raster. As long as all rasters have the same projection and are 'snapped' to one raster, so each pixel is on the same location, it should work.

Try the tool 'Extract Multi Values to Points' in ArcGIS you are using.

Comment: Thank you Tinsley.I had forgotten that all the values are different for each date ( all the 144 images have different my desired value)!

Comment: The pixel value or point, I have to know are not same in 144 images. It means first the desired point for each image must be defined, then peer to peer value must be found.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the location you wish to extract values from differs per raster?

Comment: yes, it does. The 288 images (144 ndvi-144 lst) have different values.